# can there be any philosophical interpretation of story of Menaka and Vishwamitra?

Tags: bhagavad-gita, philosophy, dharma, vishwamitra

According to the story, Indra tried to lure vishwamitra, now the question arises is that, why a god and almighty like Indra  became afraid of a sage, even with all his learned powers, the sage can not replace Indra, and if he could, does this mean that even gods have jealousy or fear? And if that was not a case then how can god allow Ravana to get blessings from Shiva if god knows about intentions of the sages. so with all this i believe that story must represent some sort of philosophical argument or teaching.